# Agora web live streaming into mobile

Tags: android, node.js, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I'm using agora as platform for streaming videos from web dashboard to android and ios devices.
I implemented the sdk with angular and nodejs. but i can't play the videos on mobile devices.
Now I'm trying to get streaming url with rtmp converter by push stream to CDN.
bUT, it require a rtmp url, I don't know how to get or create it.
I need help please.

Comment: you can try HLS instead of RTMP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Mux](https://mux.com/live/) to create a live stream URL.
Generate live stream in Mux,
Copy stream URL from Mux

Use RTMP URL like this in agora

```
rtmp://live.mux.com/app/{your-stream-key-from-mux}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use YouTube live as a rtmp address.